# How to optimise this LINQ query?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following xml that I need to deserialise to an object:

```
 <animals>
      <retrive>true</retrive>              
         <collection>
         <cat>big</cat>
         <dog>spot</dog> 
         <vetName>John Smith</vetName>              
      </collection>
    </animals>
```

This is my attempt using LINQ:

```
private Animal GetAnimalFromXML(string xml)
{
    var tempdata = (from c in data.Elements("collection")
                               select new 
                               {
                                   Cat = (string)c.Element("cat"),
                                   Dog = (string)c.Element("dog"),
                                   VetName = (string)c.Element("vetName"),
                               }).First();

    return new Animal(){
       Cat = tempdata.Cat,
       Dog = tempdata.Dog,
       VetName = tempdata.VetName
     }
}
```

I don't like that I have to use a temp object so I'm wondering if it's possible to get around this and reduce this method to just a single query?

Thanks,
d.

Comment: It is not good idea to use First method when you expect only one _collection_ element. Better way is to use Single and work with its result.

Comment: @Petr - how do you know the collection only has 1 element? Perheps the requirement is "Take the first record from the collection".

Comment: @Jamiec I suppose that, because First method is called on the whole transformed collection not on the original _collection_ elements. If there is a requirement to select the first _collection_ from many, it is more effective to select First collection and after that tranform only this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need to use the temporary data

```
private Animal GetAnimalFromXML(string xml)
{
   return (from c in data.Elements("collection")
           select new Animal()
                      {
                             Cat = (string)c.Element("cat"),
                             Dog = (string)c.Element("dog"),
                             VetName = (string)c.Element("vetName"),
                       }).First();

}
```